# jQuery smooth transition on .removeClass / .addClass atr

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition, smoothing

i'm doing a "image gallery" with css and jquery and I want to switch between images by clicking buttons. I've done it with remove/add class because it's easier and i know i can do it with "animate" but it's very complicated for me.

I don't want to use pre-made sliders, so, if you can help me, i would aprecciate that!

JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CWkQE/

i'd like that something like this could be possible:

```
$("something").addClass("someclass",1000); /* i mean adding ,1000 */
```

Comment: Adding a thousand of what?

Comment: 1000 miliseconds (commons transitions in jquery)

Comment: You really need to be very specific in your question, it is very vague right now leaving us to speculate on what you may want.

Comment: He just wants to use jQuery animations to animate changing between slides. i.e. fade etc.

Comment: exactly, but without changing the whole code

Comment: Really @adaam? Which transitions?

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to make smooth transform when switching between images. One workaround would be putting both elements one on top of another using absolute positioning and just use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions which take milliseconds as optional parameter.

Simplified sample would be something like this.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="element1">A</li>
    <li id="element2" class="hide">B</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {position: relative; height: 200px; }
li {position: absolute; }
.hide {display: none;}
```

Then instead of:

```
$("#element1").addClass("hide")
$("#element2").removeClass("hide")
```

you can do

```
$("#element1").fadeOut(1000)
$("#element2").fadeIn(1000)
```

See the concept with your sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/CWkQE/14/

Comment: Sorry, but you can't and you don't have to put classes there. This was just my mistake that I forgot to remove them. Updated my fiddle.

Comment: @KasparsOzols make sure to post your code here so that it can be preserved for perpetuity.

Comment: Added simplified example as initial fiddle was quite long